# Deleting a single row from a double pointer array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, double-pointer

Any help on deleting a single row from a double pointer array?
For example, every row of the array holds  a string of a name e.g., `'J' 'o' 'h' 'n' '\0'`. From this array full of names I want to delete a name from it.

```
char **p = malloc(arraySize*sizeof(char*));

for (i = 0;i < recordAmount;i++){
   fnames[i] = malloc(c*sizeof(char));
}

/* to summarize I scan the user data into array after I allocate memory to it */

free(*p[0]);
```

After using free indicated like in my example code above, I've discovered that the memory I'd like to free isn't being free'd and if I go to print the contents of the array, it ends up printing the data that was initially in there e.g., `'J' 'o' 'h' 'n' '\0'`. Keep in mind there are multiple names inside the array.

Comment: It is invalid (or better **Undefined Behaviour**) to access data from memory that has been freed. You were unlucky (or lucky, depending on the point of view) with that result.

Comment: You're freeing `*p[0]`, that's just wrong, you're dereferencing one time too much. `free(p[0])` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here:

```
free(*p[0]);
```

You are dereferencing one time more than you need. What you need to do to free the first row is just:

```
free(p[0]);
```

After freeing, the memory is released, and it is undefined behavior to read and write to it. If you read after freeing, anything can happen:

- You can end up reading back the exact same thing you wrote.
- You can end up reading random garbage.
- You can cause your program to crash.
- Etc...

After freeing, there is in general no need to do much more. However, if you want to make sure that data cannot be accessed anymore (to avoid undefined behavior), you can set that specific pointer to `NULL`. This is a pretty common good practice used to avoid use after free errors.

```
free(p[0]);
p[0] = NULL;

char *x = p[0]; // Fine, just reads NULL.
puts(x);        // Segmentation fault, trying to dereference NULL.
                // Memory corruption prevented.
```

Comment: Completely makes sense. Setting to NULL slipped my mind.